# What unnamed calss access rules question On different sub class

Tags: c++, c++20, unnamed-class

Super simple chain store flow statistics logic .

Parent class handle unname Object instance .

Parent class has different sub class .

In a different sub class, access parent class's unname Object, I don't know why the two unname Object are same one.

And I think they are different

Headquarters in China

```cpp
/*=================> shope.h */
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct {
  string flag = "init value";

  void print(string newFlag) {
    cout << "unnameStruct's adderss:" << this << '\t';
    cout << "flag's address:" << &flag << '\t';
    cout << "rawFlag:" << flag << '\t';
    flag = newFlag;
    cout << "newFlag:" << flag << '\t' << endl;
  }
} unnameStruct;


struct ChinaBaseShop {
  static double turnover; /* income flow */

  virtual void income(double money);
};

/*=================> shope.cpp */
#include "shope.h"

double ChinaBaseShop::turnover = {0.0};
void ChinaBaseShop::income(double money) {
  cout << "ChinaBaseShop's Address : " << this << endl;
  unnameStruct.print("Headquarters in China");
  turnover += money;
}
```

BeiJing shope

```cpp
/*=================> beijing_shope.h */
#pragma once

#include "shope.h"

struct BeijingShop : ChinaBaseShop {
  virtual void income(double money) override ;
};


/*=================> beijing_shope.cpp */
#include "beijing_shope.h"

void BeijingShop::income(double money) /* override */ {
  cout << "-BeiJing–" << endl;
  cout << "BeijingShop's Address:" << this << endl;
  unnameStruct.print("BeiJing shope");
  ChinaBaseShop::income(money);
  if(money > 100) {
    /* Over 100 minus 10 */
    turnover -= 10.0;
  }
}
```

TianJin shope

```cpp
/*=================> tianjin_shope.h */
#pragma once

#include "shope.h"

struct TianjinShop : ChinaBaseShop {
  virtual void income(double money) override ;
};

/*=================> tianjin_shope.cpp */
#include "tianjin_shope.h"

void TianjinShop::income(double money) /* override */ {
  cout << "-TianJin–" << endl;
  cout << "TianjinShop's Address:" << this << endl;
  unnameStruct.print("TianJin shope ");
  ChinaBaseShop::income(money);
  if(money >= 100) {
      /* over 100 , 10% off */
      turnover -= (money / 10.0);
  }
}
```

main file

```cpp
#include "beijing_shope.h"
#include "tianjin_shope.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  BeijingShop beijingShop;
  TianjinShop tianjinShop;

  cout << "before open any shope : " << ChinaBaseShop::turnover << endl;

  beijingShop.income(20.0);

  cout << "after open BeiJing shope : " << ChinaBaseShop::turnover << endl;

  tianjinShop.income(30.0);

  cout << "after open TianJin shope : " << ChinaBaseShop::turnover << endl;

  return 0 ;
}
```

Let's look the output :

```
g++ -std=c++20 -Wall beijing_shope.cpp  main.cpp  shope.cpp  tianjin_shope.cpp -o result.run && ./result.run

before open any shope : 0
-BeiJing–
BeijingShop's Address:0xffffef3323f8
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6108   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6108   rawFlag:init value      newFlag:BeiJing shope
ChinaBaseShop's Address : 0xffffef3323f8
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6160   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6160   rawFlag:init value      newFlag:Headquarters in China
after open BeiJing shope : 20
-TianJin–
TianjinShop's Address:0xffffef3323f0
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6188   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6188   rawFlag:init value      newFlag:TianJin shope 
ChinaBaseShop's Address : 0xffffef3323f0
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6160   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6160   rawFlag:Headquarters in China   newFlag:Headquarters in China
after open TianJin shope : 50
```

Step 1:

```
# BeiJing shop instance  and Tianjin Shope instance are different instence , 
# It is reasonable that they are address different
BeijingShop's Address:0xffffef3323f8
TianjinShop's Address:0xffffef3323f0
```

Setp 2:

```
# beijing_shope.h include shope.h , tianjin_shope.h include shope.h 
# It is reasonable that on different file unnameStruct's adderss are different 
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6108   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6108   rawFlag:init value      newFlag:BeiJing shope
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6188   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6188   rawFlag:init value      newFlag:TianJin shope
```

Step 3:

```
# On BeijingShop's instance , ChinaBaseShop::this the address is same with BeijingShop's instance . right .
# On TianjinShop's instance , ChinaBaseShop::this the address is same with TianjinShop's instance . right .
ChinaBaseShop's Address : 0xffffef3323f8
ChinaBaseShop's Address : 0xffffef3323f0
```

Step 4: Not as expected

```
# I can't understand the output
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6160   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6160   rawFlag:init value      newFlag:Headquarters in China
unnameStruct's adderss:0xaaaac85d6160   flag's address:0xaaaac85d6160   rawFlag:Headquarters in China   newFlag:Headquarters in China

# I think , BeijingShope's instance and TianjinShope's instance are different . 
# So , they super class handle different `unnameStruct` instance . 
# I think the output shoule like this :
unnameStruct's adderss:OneAddress       flag's address:OneAddress       rawFlag:init value      newFlag:Headquarters in China
unnameStruct's adderss:AnotherAddress   flag's address:AnotherAddress   rawFlag:init value      newFlag:Headquarters in China
```

Anyone will help me? Here's a [`CMake` project @ godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/K7En8qYvc) reproducing the issue.

Comment: This is a huge code dump. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @molbdnilo , So How to interpret step 2 output ?

Comment: *"Super simple"* -- to me, this suggests something that can be summed up in a sentence or two and demonstrated with maybe six lines of code. In my opinion, your context fails to be "simple", much less "super simple".

Comment: @Tom Please don't add new questions to your already answered question. Open a separate question if you need ask about something. I rolled back your addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `unnameStruct` member in any of your classes, and there is not even any connection between your classes and the "unnameStruct" name.

A variable of unnamed struct type is implicitly `static`; if you define `struct {} x;` in a header and include that header in multiple files, you will find that `&x` is different in each of those files.

So you have *four* different variables called "unnameStruct", one in each translation unit.
Each `income` function uses the `unnameStruct` variable defined in its own translation unit, and you would see yet another result if you added `unnameStruct.print("Main");` in `main`.

Comment: molbdnilo  and  @Ted Lyngmo  Thank you .  I would like to ask, where did you get this knowledge? like my update which on question end .

Comment: I read your answer , thank you .

Your answer can straighten out the train of thought and explain the phenomenon. it's very good .

I would like to ask, where did you get this knowledge? Of course , befour i ask the new question , i have read C++ 20 standerd . But i not found content as accurate as you know . I readed this :

5.1 Separate translation
6.4 Scope
A part of "6.6 Program and linkage"
I believe you , the same time , i want learn the way of learn c++ . I think look up the sources of knolege will help me in the future .

Or the source of knolege is your Experience ?

over

Comment: How to understand the fact that each translation unit holds one  `unnameStruct` instance ?